# Wordpress div "This domain has recently been listed in the marketplace"

Tags: php, wordpress, domainexpiration

This morning, I found that in all my WordPress website pages, there is an implemented div saying "This domain has recently been listed in the marketplace. Please click here to inquire."

Note that I checked my domain and I still got 2 months left before payment, I tried to upload an HTML page to test if this message appears in any page on the server, it seems that it displays only on my WordPress website www.speedaero.com.

HTML test page: www.speedaero.com/ma.html

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue, it just cropped up on my site too (but only when viewing on mobile)

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is notoriously insecure and your site has probably been hacked. Restore from backup, upgrade WP and plugins and eliminate any unnecessary plugins.

Comment: Site may be hacked..so try fresh wordpress source + DB and check again.

Answer (score 0):

It once happened to me as well. I used a theme not from a legit seller. When I removed it and use a default theme - Twenty Sixteen theme from wordpress.org - the div tag contains above notification is gone.

Just try to disable your current theme then install and activate a default theme.